# Prevent the delete key from working on Kendo ListBox

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

I'm using Kendo on Razor pages using MVVM.  On a particular page I have a pair of ListBoxes. I want to stop users from deleting items from the boxes with the delete key.

If I trap and prevent the `remove` event from working, that solves the problem, except you can't then use the toolbox or drag and drop to transfer items from one box to the other (edit: because move is a combination of change & remove events).

This is how I was stopping the remove event...

```
<select style="min-width: 600px" id="listboxImports" data-role="listbox"
    data-text-field="title"
    data-value-field="id"
    data-selectable="multiple"
    data-toolbar='{tools: ["transferTo", "transferFrom"]}'
    data-connect-with="listboxSelected"
    data-draggable="true"
    data-template="template"
    data-drop-sources="['listboxSelected']"
    data-bind="source: imports, events: {remove: viewmodel.events.remove}"></select>

<script>
    var viewmodel = new kendo.observable({
        events: {
            remove: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            },
            //
        }
    });
<script/>
```

I've also tried to trap the delete key's `keydown` event, but I cannot identify which of the many elements rendered when the ListBox is rendered is actually handling the event.

Can anyone tell me how I can have my cake *and* eat it please?

Comment: Please show us a sample of what you did so far.

Comment: @FrozenButcher, I've added some detail to the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took ma a while, inspired by the same question for kendo's Multiselect: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/multiselect/how-to/selection/prevent-removing-selected-items-on-backspace:

```
  $("#listBoxA").parent().get(0).addEventListener('keydown',  function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == kendo.keys.DELETE) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();  
        e.preventDefault();
      }
 }, true)
```

Full dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/aFaCIkez/3

The _keyDown handler is attached to the <ul> element. My solution attaches a new handler to its parent, using [event capturing](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-events/), so that handler will be executed before Kendo's, and thus stopping the event's propagation if the pressed key was delete.

Alternatively, a possible workaround is to set `navigatable` to false, but you obviously lose all keyboard functionality. Example: https://dojo.telerik.com/IHICAziR

Comment: GaloisGirl, My Hero.